# Unable to install a local maven artefact to remote repository, google-android-maps

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm in the process of setting up a Jenkins build environment to build my android projects. For the most part its OK however there are some dependencies that are not available in the central repository, such as the Google Android Maps API, therefore I need to install it to my remote repository manually. I've got these install to my local repo using `mvn install` and that works fine.

I've done some googling, and have the following configuration so far, but I'm seeing the following errors when I try to deploy the maps jar to my remote repo.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.google.android.maps -DartifactId=maps -Dversion=8_r1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:\Users\James\.m2\repository\com\google\android\maps\maps\8_r1\maps-8_r1.jar -DrepositoryId=cloudbeesreleases -Durl=https://repository-myusername.forge.cloudbees.com/release/
```

and I see this :

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.450s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Feb 18 17:01:06 GMT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/92M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Cannot deploy artifact from the local repository: C:\Users\James\.m2\repository\com\google\android\maps\maps\8_r1\maps-8_r1.jar -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Cannot deploy artifact from the local repository: C:\Users\James\.m2\repository\com\google\android\maps\maps\8_r1\maps-8_r1.jar
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Cannot deploy artifact from the local repository: C:\Users\James\.m2\repository\com\google\android\maps\maps\8_r1\maps-8_r1.jar
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute(DeployFileMojo.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I've got the following in my `settings.xml`

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>artifactory</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>cloudbeesreleases</id>
          <name>libs-releases</name>
          <url>https://repository-myusername.forge.cloudbees.com/release/</url>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>        
      </repositories>      
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

Have I got something misconfigured, or am I completely misunderstanding how the `deploy` should work?

Answer (score 24):

The error message seems straightforward.

> Cannot deploy artifact from the local repository:...

Can you try deploying the file placing it in a different location?  Also [this discussion](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/doubt-in-maven-deploy-plugin-deploy-file-goal-tp122273.html) seems to be on the same problem and states why there is a problem.

Comment: I had the same problem, so I copied the artifact to /tmp/ and tried deploying from that location instead.  It worked!

Comment: Thanks, copying the file outside the maven local repo solves the issue!

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to override this behavior (e.g. --force), since there are a variety of scenarios where a user might actually need to do this... having to copy the file out of the repository is sort of a hack.

Answer (score 5):

Putting together Raghuram's answer and neu242's comment was the solution for me. For clarity's sake:

```
cp ~/.m2/repository/path/to/jar/api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /tmp/.
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.mygroup -DartifactId=api -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Durl=file:./local-maven-repo/ -DrepositoryId=local-maven-repo -DupdateReleaseInfo=true -Dfile=/tmp/api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dpackaging=jar
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:
Use the settings parameter to make sure the correct settings file is being used, there multiple ones with a hierarchy.

```
--settings <arg>
```

Does the log output say some thing like uploading http://..... is the URL correct and what you would expect it to be?

Is uploading them manually using the sonatype front end an option?

Shouldn't your settings file also have a server tag:

```
<server>
  <id>deploymentRepo</id>
  <username>repouser</username>
  <password>repopwd</password>
</server>
```

The [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) say "Server Id to map on the  under  section of settings.xml" so I am guessing it will not work without a matching server configuration.